# Can we compute Fourier series of any function this way?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series, taylor-expansion

There is a technique to compute Fourier series much quickly, but I doubt how general this technique can be. Let's look at a simple example to see how the technique goes.

Compute Fourier series of the $2\pi$ periodic function 
$\dfrac{2\sin\theta}{5-4\cos\theta}$:

> Note(if we are gifted enough ^_^) that $\dfrac{2\sin\theta}{5-4\cos\theta}$ is a special case of the function
>   $v(r,\theta) = \dfrac{r\sin\theta}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}$ when $r = \frac{1}{2}$.
>   And $v(r,\theta)$ is the imaginary part of the complex function
>   $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{1-z}$ with $z = re^{i\theta}$.
>   Expanding $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{1-z} = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + \cdots$, 
>   substituting $z =  re^{i\theta}$,
>   and pick up the imaginary part,
>   we have
>   $v(r,\theta) = r\sin\theta + r^2\sin 2\theta + r^3\sin 3\theta +\cdots$.
>
> Letting $r = \frac{1}{2}$,
>   we derive the Fourier series of $v(\frac{1}{2},\theta)=\dfrac{2\sin\theta}{5-4\cos\theta}$, i.e.
>
> $\tilde{v}(\frac{1}{2},\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\sin\theta + \frac{1}{2^2}\sin 2\theta + \frac{1}{2^3}\sin 3\theta
> + \cdots$.

I wonder whether the above approach can be applied to compute any or most $2\pi$ periodic function's Fourier series ?
If not, what conditions should be put on the function to guarantee success of the above approach ?
(If necessary, we may suppose all series we meet are convergent.)

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "the aboive". $v(r,\theta)$ with arbitrary $r$? Linear combinations of such $v$? Functions that are imaginary parts of complex functions with well-known Taylor expansion? Arbirtrary analytic periodic functions? Arbitrary continuous periodic functions? Arbitrary periodic $L_2$ integrable funcitons? Arbitrary periodic function?

Comment: It depends on what you call "the above approach" and "most $2\pi$-periodic function". Something along these lines is certainly possible if e.g. your function is rational in $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$.

Comment: In short, the above approach states that: there exists an $r0$, a complex function with well-known Taylor expansion whose imaginary part is $v(r,\theta)$, such that the function $f(\theta)$ we want to expand can be expressed as $f(\theta) = v(r0,\theta)$.

Comment: I found the approach in a book and wonder its applicability.

Comment: Not all the functions can be a real (or imaginary) part of a holomorphic (or analytic) function. You have to ask this function to be harmonic. I think "if we are gifted enough..." then we can use this method to similar functions, like @O.L. said. But I don't think it's a really useful method...

Comment: Well, for 'most functions', I mean functions we meet in calculus exercises or exams, and weird functions are not included in this topic.

Comment: @booksee I wonder you gave the answer of your question almost yourself if you have "a special case of the function...", when "$r=1/2$", and "$v(r,\theta)$ the imaginary part of..." ... ...all these conditions presumed...

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi I found the method to compute Fourier series in a book named [_Visual Complex Analysis_](http://usf.usfca.edu/vca//), and I don't think this example adequately explains the philosophy in page77 of the book '_Taylor series and Fourier series of real functions are merely two different ways of viewing complex power series_'... As far as I am concerned, it is not an easy task to judge whether a real function(even a very simple one) is a real part or an imaginary part of a (holomorphic) complex function and find out the complex function...